Flutter app executable is not working on linux
I am working on a mail client in flutter. I am using objectbox in my flutter app to store mails in cache, but when I built the app using command
flutter build linux --release
And created an executable, which runs fine on my device, but when ran on other devices, it gives the following error
./my_project: error while loading shared libraries: libobjectbox.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I tried finding the file and it was n the bundle/lib directory, but still it shows no such file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Seems like your application called "my_project". To inspect the its system library dependencies, use the following commands:
$ flutter build linux --release
$ ldd build/linux/x64/release/bundle/my_project

To wrap up this application for distribution, include everything in the bundle directory and verify the target linux system has all required sys libraries.
You can use the following command:
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libblkid1 liblzma5


I did this to generate the executable, but when I run the executable on other linux device, I get the error that I had shared in my question

You can download a copy of the libobjectbox.so library using
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/main/install.sh)

Then ship the libobjectbox.so with your application executable in a lib folder. (Source: https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started in Dart Native tab.)
But it's odd, I thought Flutter would bundle this as part of the executable. If you want, feel free to open an issue (https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues) to discuss/analyze this further.
